# How to match the exact word with length

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone help me on this regex, i need to replace the text which match with text with the same length.

> "StateQuestion".replace(/State/gi, 'YES')

As per the regex, it searches for state and replaces with YES and the output is YESQuestion.

But I need to have the regex to detect the exact word State and not with StateQuestion. How to modify this script, please help on here

Comment: Can you give more examples? If you need `State` to be a standalone word and not part of another word, use word boundaries?

Comment: Or anchors: `/^State$/`?

Answer (score 3):

Put word boundaries around the individual word you want to target:

```js
console.log("StateQuestion".replace(/\bState\b/gi, 'YES'));
console.log("New York is a lovely State.".replace(/\bState\b/gi, 'YES'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for your problem. I think this will work fine

```js
var str = "State StateQuestion State state";
var p = /\bState\b/gi;
mod_str = str.replace(p, "Yes");
console.log(mod_str)
```